# Java initializing a generic array

Tags: java, generics

```
  T[] genericArray= (T[])(new Object[2]);
```

T has a constraint that it implements Comparable. The line above fails with an exception

```
" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; 
cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Comparable;
```

How do I initialize a generic array where the T has constraints?

Comment: Please check that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18292315/524743

Comment: *Why* do you need an array of type `T[]`?

Comment: I used an array of type T because later on in the code I do T[0] =...,T[1]=.. and so on. I need to return a collection of objects that are all of type T. Does not have to be an array. Any collection would do.

Comment: There is no need for the array to be of type `T[]` when all you want to do is `array[…] = …;`. An array of type `Object[]` will support this too. For all other operations, a collection, most likely an `ArrayList` will serve much better.

Answer (score 3):

`Object` doesn't implements `Comparable`.

Instead of creating it as `Object[]` create it as `Comparable[]`.

Related to your comment:

A variable can be declared of any type. When you create an array you are not creating objects inside the array, but you are only allocating the memory to store the references to the objects.

So as you can write:

```
Comparable x = "Pippo"; // Because String is Comparable
```

you can also write

```
Comparable[] x = new Comparable[1];
x[0] = "Pippo";    // Here you add a concrete String that is a
                   // Comparable type on the first position
```

Comment: How? You cannot create an instance of an interface.

Comment: You can create an array of interfaces. But you need to add concrete elements inside it. For example Comparable[] x = new Comparable[1]; x[0] = "This is comparable";

Comment: From your first sentence, you might be missing the context of the question (which is that `(T[])new Object[n]` is a common way to create an array "of the generic type")

Comment: T could have any constraint on it. Is there a way not to enforce all those constraints again?

Comment: Wich constraints are you saying?

Comment: Like along with comparable, it could also be serializable or something that might get enforced later on.

Comment: @developer747: changing the bounds of `T` is an incompatible change and may break much more than just one array creation. However, usually these bounds are fixed right within the same class containing the array creation.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because `Object` does not implement `Comparable` and thus `Object[]` is not a sub-type of `Comparable[]` (which, because of type erasure, is the runtime type of your `genericArray`).

The underlying problem is that you want to create a generic array. *This is not possible in Java.* The reason is, that unlike generics, the type of the elements of an array is known at runtime. If you write `new T[]`, it is not known which type of array must be created.

You try to circumvent this by creating an array of some supertype. But this is also not correct (and you should get a warning if you do it). If you create a an array with `new Comparable[size]`, you create a an array of `Comparable`s, *not* an array of some subtype of `Comparable`. A `T[]` might be a `String[]` or a `Long[]`, and `String[]` and `Long[]` are different types than `Comparable[]` (also at runtime).

To demonstrate the problem, consider the following program:

```
public class Foo<T extends Comparable> {    
    T[] createArray() {
        return (T[])new Comparable[1];
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>();
        String[] ss = foo.createArray(); // here
    }
}
```

It might look perfectly okay at first sight, but when your run it, you get a `ClassCastException`, because in the marked line a `Object[]` is cast to a `String[]`.

The solution is to use `Class<T>` objects as so-called *type tokens*. These let you store the type so that you can access it at run-time. Now you can create an array with the correct type by using `Array.newInstance(Class<T>, int...)`. For example:

```
public class Foo<T extends Comparable> {
    private Class<T> type;

    public Foo(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    T[] createArray() {
        return (T[])Array.newInstance(type, 1);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>(String.class);
        String[] ss = foo.createArray();
    }
}
```

(You may still get a warning from the compiler, because `newInstance`'s return type is `Object`. You can ignore it because the object it returns is an array of the correct type.)